# Using SwingWorker publish efficiently

Tags: java, swing, multithreading

I am using `SwingWorker` to query a server process for a large number of "result" objects on a background thread.  As individual results arrive I want to publish them and display them on the GUI.

My question is: Given that I will be receiving potentially thousands of results is it more efficient to call `publish(V... chunks)` for every N results or should I just call `publish` for each event received?

I see that the documentation states that multiple calls to `publish` will be coalesced into a single call to `process` but wasn't sure if it was still better to retain some form of control in my own code by throttling **when I call publish**.  What do people recommend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I say do the simplest thing that works - leave it to the Swing API to perform the throttling and if you run into problems later on it'll be an easy fix to add additional throttling yourself at that time (plus you'll have the justification for doing so).

Comment: Cool - That's what I was thinking of doing.